# How to declare several stylable attributes with the same name for different tags?

Tags: java, android, xml, declare-styleable, styleable

I want both my ViewA and ViewB to have the "title" tag. But I can't put this in `attrs.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ViewA">
        <attr name="title" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="ViewB">
        <attr name="title" format="string" />
        <attr name="max" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

because of the error *Attribute "title" has already been defined*. [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434327/same-named-attributes-in-attrs-xml-for-custom-view/4464966#4464966) shows this solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="title" format="string" />
    <declare-styleable name="ViewB">
        <attr name="max" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

but in that case, `R.styleable.ViewA_title` and `R.styleable.ViewB_title` are not generated. I need them for reading the attributes from the AttributeSet using the following code:

```
TypedArray a=getContext().obtainStyledAttributes( as, R.styleable.ViewA);
String title = a.getString(R.styleable.ViewA_title);
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434327/same-named-attributes-in-attrs-xml-for-custom-view

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The link you have posted does give you the correct answer. This is what it suggests you do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="title" format="string" />
    <declare-styleable name="ViewA">
        <attr name="title" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="ViewB">
        <attr name="title" />
        <attr name="max" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Now, `R.styleable.ViewA_title`and `R.styleable.ViewB_title`are both accessible.

If you get a chance, read through this answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3441986). Relevant quote:

> You can define attributes in the top  element or inside of
>   a  element. If I'm going to use an attr in more
>   than one place I put it in the root element.

Comment: **Update 2022;** This works just fine! (tested with latest Android Studio and Gradle)

Answer (score 5):

Do this instead. No `parent` tag needed

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ViewA">
        <attr name="title" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="ViewB" >
        <attr name="title" /> 
        <attr name="min" format="integer" />
        <attr name="max" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This is because once `title` is declared in `ViewA`, it doesn't need (and also can't) to be declared in again in another `declare-styleable`

Comment: If I understand this correctly, then the `resources` tag forms a frame for inheritance, right? So the `title` attribute would not be automatically inherited in another file, right? Or am I missing something? Could you please clarify this in your answer?

Comment: @BenjaminBasmaci No such frame, define once, and use all over the module (without repeating type).

Answer (score 4):

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="ViewA">
    <attr name="title" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>

<declare-styleable name="ViewB" parent="ViewA"> // inherit from ViewA
    <attr name="min" format="integer" />
    <attr name="max" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

This doesn't work。

```
<resources>
<attr name="title" format="string" />
<declare-styleable name="ViewA">
    <attr name="title" />
</declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="ViewB">
    <attr name="title" />
    <attr name="max" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

This also doesn't work。

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="ViewA">
    <attr name="title" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>

<declare-styleable name="ViewB" >
    <attr name="title" /> 
    <attr name="min" format="integer" />
    <attr name="max" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**This was OK!!**

Answer (score 3):

You need to use inheritance

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ViewA">
        <attr name="title" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="ViewB" parent="ViewA"> // inherit from ViewA
        <attr name="min" format="integer" />
        <attr name="max" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In your java code

```
String namespace = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/" + getContext().getPackageName();
int title_resource = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(namespace, "title", 0); 
String title = "";
if(title_resource!=0){
  title = getContext().getString(title_resource);
}

int min = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(namespace, "min", 0); // read int value
int max = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(namespace, "max", 0);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't generate ViewB_title. ViewA_title can't be used for ViewB elements since its ID would clash with ViewB_min.