# How to avoid duplicate value for resource 'attr/*' in CustomView

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-styles, android-attributes

If I import:

**CustomViewA** (imported from Maven)

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomViewA">
        <attr name="min" format="float"/>
        <attr name="max" format="float"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

**CustomViewB** (imported from Maven)

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomViewB">
        <attr name="min" format="float"/>
        <attr name="max" format="float"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

This will fail saying that **min** and **max** are duplicated. I thought Android would distinguish by the `declare-styleable name`, but guess not. Saying that, what's the best way to name a custom View *`attr`* to avoid any possible duplicate value clash in the future?

The only solution I got so far is:

```
<attr name="minForMyCustomViewHopingNoOneUsesThisName" format="float"/>
```

Which sucks.

Comment: Until namespaces are introduced this is our only option.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4464966/4390987

Answer (score 5):

you can do this

```
<attr name="min" format="float" />
<attr name="max" format="float" />

<declare-styleable name="CustomViewA">
    <attr name="min" />
    <attr name="max" />
</declare-styleable>

<declare-styleable name="CustomViewB">
   <attr name="min" />
   <attr name="max" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: Will this work if I'm the `CustomViewA` owner but not from `CustomViewB`? Assuming that the `CustomViewB` developer uses the `attr` outside of the `declare-styleable` and/or inside?

Comment: can't understand. what are you saying?

Comment: Let's say that in my custom lib I use your approach. Then I import another Lib that uses the same approach. Will it collide?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. No, it will not collide. It will be working fine if both libs have the same `attr elements`

Comment: yes, it will work fine with a different format and the same name in a different module

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work if CustomViewA (maven import) uses your approach but CustomViewB (maven import) does not. Just tested.

Answer (score 0):

To make it unique is the ultimate answer. 
I prepare to use

```
<attr name="custom_view_a_min" format="float"/>
<attr name="custom_view_b_min" format="float"/>
```